# FragmentTabHost tab not visible after setCurrentTab()

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, fragment-tab-host

In my current project, I have a `FragmentTabHost` that manages six tabs.  Inside the `onSaveInstanceState()` of the parent fragment, I save the current index of the selected tab, and then restore it in `onCreateView()`.  All of this works fine, except for the visibility.  When I restore the instance state and call `setCurrentTab()`, the correct tab is re-selected as it should be, but that tab isn't visible, as the `FragmentTabHost` seems to want to make the first tab visible as though it's the one that's selected.

Is there any way to position the tabs such that a programmatically-selected tab is always visible on the screen?  Also, the `FragmentTabHost` is contained within a `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

         <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE #1** : After some more digging, I thought the following might provide some answers.  Although the documentation states that the vast majority of the the tabbed functionality should go through `FragmentTabHost` instead of `TabWidget`, I tried the following after getting the reference to `TabWidget`:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView() : Getting player data from saved instance");

    // Restore value of members from saved state
    player = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(ARG_PLAYER);
    populate();

    // Reselect the tab that was active when the fragment got swapped out
    int currentTab = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_CURRENT_TAB);
    fragmentTabHost.setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    tabWidget.focusCurrentTab(currentTab);   <---- added this
} else {
    ...
}
```

I am beginning to think I'm going to have to write some custom code for the `HorizontalScrollView` to calculate where the currently-selected tab is and scroll it myself, but that's a last resort.